# Are dog breeds capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

When writing of dog breeds should they be capitalized? For example:

> The best breed for hunting rabbits is the beagle.

Should the word "beagle" be capitalized?

Answer (score 5):

Typically, breeds are not capitalized in general-interest publications, like popular magazines and books and newspapers (see [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/22/opinion/sunday/beware-the-beagle.html?rref=collection%2Ftimestopic%2FDogs&action=click&contentCollection=science&region=stream&module=stream_unit&version=search&contentPlacement=1&pgtype=collection) from the NYT, for example). Common editorial practice follows the guidance of dictionaries like Merriam-Webster's and American Heritage. If you look up *beagle* or *poodle* in either of these sources, you will see that it is lower case. German shepherds, Portuguese water dogs, Newfoundland hounds, Dalmatians, and others that include a proper term do take capitals on those terms.

However, if you go to a site like the American Kennel Club's ([www.akc.org](http://www.akc.org)), generally you'll see capitals used for all breeds, including *Beagle* and *Poodle*. This is a perfectly reasonable editorial decision, given that breeds and breeding are their entire focus.

In short, capitalization is an editorial choice.

Comment: It bugs me when people write "labrador" without a capital - the breed is named after Labrador in Canada. Or should I say labrador in canada?

Answer (score 1):

Usually not, the one exception being "the Beagle" when referring to any given beagle, ie. the breed as a whole.